# Ionic error, al tratar de compilar con ionic serve

Tags: ionic2, ionic-framework

Me da el siguiente error:

> declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Donde `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { PendientesPage } from '../pages/pendientes/pendientes';
import { LeidosPage } from '../pages/leidos/leidos';
import { TodosPage } from '../pages/todos/todos';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
//utilitarios
import { GenerarCodigoControl } from '../utilitarios/generar.codigo.control';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    TodosPage,
    LeidosPage,
    PendientesPage,
    TabsPage,
    GenerarCodigoControl
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    TodosPage,
    LeidosPage,
    PendientesPage,
    TabsPage,
    GenerarCodigoControl
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Y el otro código de GenerarCodigoControl:

```
import { Validar } from './validar';
import { AllegedRc4 } from './allegedrc4';
import { Base64 } from './base64';
import { Verhoeff } from './verhoeff';
export class GenerarCodigoControl {
          //var oValidar: Validar;
           constructor(private oValidar:Validar, private oAllegedRc4:AllegedRc4, private oBase64:Base64,private oVerhoeff:Verhoeff){
           }
          enviarDatos1(){
           this.oValidar.validarDatos(2345,334,45,'25/09/2018',232,'Sesamo');
          }
}
```

¿Cual es el error? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El error es mostrado porque el componente que estás agregando no tiene la anotación `@Component({...})`

Para solucionar el error necesitas agregar algo como esto:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-generar-codigo-control',
    templateUrl: './generar-codigo-control.component.html'  
})
export class GenerarCodigoControl {
    //var oValidar: Validar;
    constructor(private oValidar: Validar, private oAllegedRc4: AllegedRc4, private oBase64: Base64, private oVerhoeff: Verhoeff) {}
    enviarDatos1() {
        this.oValidar.validarDatos(2345, 334, 45, '25/09/2018', 232, 'Sesamo');
    }
}
...
```

Sin esta información Angular no sabe cómo procesar tu componente.

Para más información puedes revisar la documentación oficial:

https://angular.io/api/core/Component

**EDIT:**

Considerando que quieres añadir como un servicio la clase *GenerarCodigoControl* necesitas agregar la anotación `@Injectable` de la siguiente forma:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class GenerarCodigoControl {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Enseguida inyectando este servicio por medio del constructor de la clase donde quieras utilizarlo podrás hacer uso de el sin ningún problema.

Comment: Estimado llamo desde tabs.ts:import { Component } from '@angular/core'; import {GenerarCodigoControl} from '../../utilitarios/generar.codigo.control'; 
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})

export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = PendientesPage;
  tab2Root = LeidosPage;
  tab3Root = TodosPage;

  constructor(private oGenerarCodigoControl:GenerarCodigoControl) {
  }
  enviando()
  {
    this.oGenerarCodigoControl.enviarDatos1();
  }
}

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que la clase *GenerarCodigoControl* la quieres utilizar como un servicio. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Exactamente estimado, creo que esa es la mejor solucion utilizarlo como servicio

Comment: En ese caso sería bueno que agregaras la anotación `@Injectable()` sobre la clase _GenerarCodigoControl_ y hacer la inyección de dependencias por medio del controlador (tal como lo estás haciendo en _tabs.ts_ ).

Comment: Estimados cree un servicio y ahi **recien funciona**, gracias por sus aportes

Comment: Actualizaré mi respuesta con los comentarios que hiciste para solucionar tu problema con un servicio.